# Complexity proof

Tags: proof, asymptotic-complexity

I would to prove the following example:

```
n^k = O (c^n) for every k and c>1
```

It is noticeable that the polynomial function grows faster than exponential function. We try to find k0 > 0 satisfying the condition

```
fn > = k0 * g(n)
```

Than

```
n^k <= k0 * c^n
log(n^k) <= log (k0 * c^n)
log(n^(k/n)) <= log (k0 * c)
k0 >= 1/c*n^(k/n)
```

So, k0 > 0, positive and small enough, while the value of c is irrelevant... Is it OK?

Comment: Without taking the time to write it out, step 3 bothers me, I am not convinced you can do that with logs. (note- ever read Lamport's paper on proofs? it's worth a read).

Comment: Paul is correct, you can't do that with logs in step 3. log(c^n) = n * log (c). Therefore step 3 should be: (log(n^k))/n <= log (k0 * c)

Comment: Thanx, there is a mistake in step 3, I wrote it fast and did not check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
log(n^k) <= log (k0 * c^n)
k log n <= log k0 + n log c

k log n - n log c <= log k0
log (n^k) - log (c^n) <= log k0
log ((n^k) / (c^n)) <= log k0 | expo
(n^k) / (c^n) <= k0
n^k <= k0 * c^n

=> n^k = O(c^n)
```

Your step 3 seems wrong, at least I don't see where you got it from. Your conclusion also doesn't seem to prove what was asked for.